# Performance of using value in property vs variable

Tags: c#, performance, memory, performance-testing, cpu-cache

Leading note; yes, I know this is not necessarily worth optimising, I'm asking out of interest.

Inside a property, where we have access to `value`, is there any known performance difference between `value` and the backing field? For example:

```
set
{
    x = value;
    if(x == y)
        ...
}
```

vs

```
set
{
    x = value;
    if(value == y)
        ...
}
```

As I understand it, `value` is always forcibly pinned when handed over. I assume `value` is also present in the L1 cache, or readily available in a register on hand.

Can anybody provide a detailed overview of how `value` is handled in terms of access? Also, a note for anyone wondering why I haven't simply tested this; it would of course require a very specific isolated test setup to get any meaningful results out of, so I felt that asking about the locality of how it's handled would be more appropriate.

Comment: How do you have access to `value` in a `get`?

Comment: Because I'm an idiot, any typed it up too quickly. Thanks :)

Comment: Just *measure* it. Use a `StopWatch`, call the setter a decent number of times (e.g. 1million times) and check which runs faster. Nothing "specific isolated" nneds to be done here. The `value` is nothing but a methpd-argument and the `set` is nothing but a void-method expecting that single `value`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure (though I didn't check the specs or the emitted IL) that `value` is a normal parameter of the property's `set` method: `public void propertySet(type value)`. Properties are just syntactic sugar for a `propertyGet` and `propertySet` method.

Comment: I guess it's a set?!? Is the backing variable volatile? is this being used where threads are involved?  otherwise you aren't going to see any difference in use, nothing worth worrying about...

Comment: One thing to consider, albeit not performance related, is that the variable 'x' could be changed by another thread between the two lines in the first sample.  The latter is a more certain comparison.

Comment: @HimBromBeere as I said, it wouldn't be worthwhile benchmarking this outside of an isolated environment if you are expecting any meaningful or accurate results. The performance difference will be so minor (and I'm more interested in how it's handled than raw performance) that everything from memory locality to system load would cause pretty major inaccuracies, and I don't want to set that up for a quick question out of interest.

Comment: That´s why I wrote *repeat a decent amount of times*, not just once. Do it e.g. 10000000 times and you´ll see the difference - if any. It´s not that hard to call a setter some thousand of times and to use a `StopWatch`, is it?

Comment: @HimBromBeere you edited that, if we're nitpicking, and that was assumed. Regardless of how many times you run it, outside of an isolated setup there are too many inaccuracies to get any sort of meaningful result. Sure, with rearrangement to account for memory locality you could get an average of which is faster,  but that doesn't necessarily translate to an actual use case (and again, my question was more about the handling of `value` in memory, not the raw performance).

Comment: @Anon A setter is just candy for a method that is meant to set a field. `value` is in reality just a parameter of that method.

Comment: Your "isolated setup" is nothing but a console-program with a single class containing a single property and a million accesses to this properties setter. Nothing you couldn´t do yourself.